# Looking for rpg rules system suggestions

Tags: game-recommendation

I'm looking for an RPG rule system that has the following elements, or at least the majority of them.

- Not too crunchy. New World of Darkness is the limit for me.
- Plenty of material published or PDF books.
- Diversity of Settings: supernatural, mystery, fantasy, martial arts.
- No levels
- Mechanical narratives, as Fate's aspects.
- Templates for races and professions. Something like the Savage Worlds professionals edges, but with more options, more detailed, more complete.
- Vitality system, something like the New World of Darkness.
- A system of morality and corruption. I like the rules of the New World of Darkness and The One Ring.
- Dangers, hazards and challenges as in Mouse Guard, The One Ring or Fate Fractal rules. Meaning rules that approach environment hazards and challenges as conflicts.

Comment: Do you have an overall goal as to what you want to do with this system, such that you're requesting this combination of features?

Comment: you mention Mouse guard's challenges. What *aspect* of those challenges are you interested in? The "failure creates more adventure?" or just the mechanics of mouse versus environment? Can you tell us why the systems you've specified *don't* work for what you want?

Comment: From "Meaning rules that approach environment hazards and challenges as conflicts." it sounds like he wants to be able to mechanically represent the environment the same way as he would an opponent? I think? But I'm not sure how The One Ring does that.  I have no suggestions that hit all of these.  Closest I get is Tenra Bansho Zero, which misses out on Diversity of Settings and Dangers/Hazards.

Comment: The community appears to be unclear on some of your more important criteria, so I'm putting answering on hold for now. If you can clear up these points of uncertainty, please edit the question with such clarifications so that answering can resume. Thanks!